# Is it safe to use php proxy to do https request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, proxy, cors, xmlhttprequest

As you know you can not make http requests to sites that do not have the http header that allows it using JavaScript in browsers because of CORS. I need to make https requests containing sensitive data. I do not want to get in touch with this sensitive data, in fact all this will be client side with javascript, only for the reason mentioned above I need to use a php proxy such as CORS Anywhere or my own, the question is: if I use these proxies to make https requests directly to the direct interested server, will the proxy have any information regarding the data sent? Sorry for my bad english, I use the translator.

Comment: Yes, making a proxied request with sensitive data will require the proxy to send the sensitive data to the actual target. There's no way to avoid that.

Comment: Where does your page get the sensitive data from, anyway? You must get in touch with the data to send it anywhere, doesn't matter much whether your application touches it on the client or on your server.

Comment: @Bergi No, because the data are wrote by the user, so javascript get data directly, all in client side.

Comment: @Bergi But the ssl encryption is born for prevent man in the middle attack like a http proxy, in a normal http proxy if you go to a https web site all will be encrypted, isn't possible to make a things like this with a php proxy?

Comment: Yes, javascript is getting the data: *your* javascript is getting the data, therefore you touch it. You may try to avoid touching it, but there's nothing to stop you - and the user can't ensure that other than by trusting you - they entrust you with their data.

Comment: Yes, you cannot make a proxy that serves the foreign data with the foreign certificate under your own domain.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? It sounds like there might be a much better solution than to use a proxy, like have the third party enable CORS for you.

Comment: @Bergi A user can see that I absolutely do not touch his data by inspecting the javascript, in this way he can see what javascript does with his data, however I can not tell the server that he will have to receive the data to enable CORS or something, because what I want to do is to automate actions in a site account, so it would be almost impossible to tell that site to put CORS.

Comment: Sounds like you either have to write a userscript that runs in that very site, or you have to get the user to enter their credentials for the account in your site. There's no way around that.

Comment: @Bergi I have found the solution

Comment: @Bergi Uhm I cannot post answers, so I have wrote it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/8mdkBugp